# How can I combine multiple styles of fonts into one rule?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Using the `@font-face` rule multiple times, you can specify different font files for different styles of the base font. E.g:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(myFont.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(myFontBold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

However, when you make a new rule for each style (bold, italic, bold-italic, etc), a lot of code is repeated:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: roboto;
  src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: roboto;
  src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: roboto;
  src: url(fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: roboto;
  src: url(fonts/roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype');
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Is there a more efficient way to write this?** i.e. can I combine the styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, as far as I know, your approach is the best way to specify each style within each font.

After your set up, if you apply font-family:'roboto', with italic and bold, it will automatically fetch the font file from 'Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf' for example.

If you want to have shorter and easier way to write it and not bother about the font presentation so much, I would suggest you just apply 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' the single font file will do. It will still response to the css bold and italic, just that it will not be as accurate as the original font.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the font styles accurate, so the font face rules will have to stay as-is. I'm going to wait a day or two and see if anyone else has any ideas; if not, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score -1):

replace each font-family: roboto; to type.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: robotoRegular;
    src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: robotoBold;
    src: url('fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: robotoItalic;
    src: url(fonts/roboto/Roboto-Italic.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: robotoBoldItalic;
    src: url(fonts/roboto/Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf) format('truetype');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: How is this less code than beforehand? In fact, it requires *more* code. This does not answer my question at all.